# How to set video length 3/4 time more then original?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation

I want to export video 3 time more then original (same video repeated 3 times). That means the 2 second video will be 6 second. So how this is possible ?

I have already implemented that export video and save it in cameraroll. 
so please suggest me what is best way to do this.

Comment: repeat the video 3 times... why you want to make video or big size?

Comment: because I want to share it in wat's app so it would be looking good. 2 second video has no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

/*******************Code for increase video length*****************************************/

AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
CMTime videoLength = videoAsset.duration;
if(self.isVideo){
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:videoAsset.duration error:nil];
    videoLength = CMTimeAdd(videoAsset.duration, videoAsset.duration);
}
[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

//slow down whole video by 2.0
double videoScaleFactor = scalfactor;
CMTime videoDuration = videoLength;
[compositionVideoTrack scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration)
                           toDuration:CMTimeMake(videoDuration.value/videoScaleFactor, videoDuration.timescale)];

CGSize videoSize = [clipVideoTrack naturalSize];

/******************* End Code *************************************************************/
```